# C binary reaches 1.2G memory limit

Tags: c, memory, memory-management, 64-bit, out-of-memory

I am dealing with a C program that reads in from a file with many
lines of about 60 characters each and allocates the string in memory
by requesting more memory as it reads the file in. After each `malloc`
request, it checks with a function `OOM()` if the request for more
memory was successful.

I have tested the program with an increasingly larger input file, and
`OOM()` reports an `"Out of memory"` more or less when the memory
usage reaches 1.2G when looking at the `top` command while the program
is running. This is on a 64bit linux machine with plenty more memory
available. Output from `file /my/binary/program`:

```
ELF 64-bit LSB executable, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked (uses shared libs), for GNU/Linux 2.6.18, not stripped
```

My question is: why is it reaching the 1.2G limit? I remember my
sysadmin used to say that certain binaries would only be able to use
up to 1.2G, which coincidentally is what I am seeing here.

When I run `qsub` the same execution on a node of the same 64bit Linux
SGE grid reserving 50GB of memory, it reports that also goes `"Out of
memory"` and the following SGE log memory footprint:

```
Max vmem         = 2.313G
```

Any ideas why the program is reaching this memory limit? Are there any
compilation flags I should be aware of which could cause/solve this?

Find below the relevant flags in the current `Makefile`:

```
CC = gcc
CFLAGS = -Wall -O3 -funroll-loops -DNDEBUG -fomit-frame-pointer -std=gnu99 -msse2 -Wno-unused-function -Wno-unused-result
CFLAGSSFMT = -msse2 -DHAVE_SSE2 -O9 -finline-functions -fomit-frame-pointer \
-DNDEBUG -fno-strict-aliasing --param max-inline-insns-single=1800 -std=c99
LD = ld
LDFLAGS =  -lm -lc -lblas -llapack
INCFLAGS = 
DEFINES = -D_GNU_SOURCE -DUSE_BLAS
```

Some of the relevant code belo:w

in `mystring.h`:

```
#ifndef _MYSTRING_H_
#define _MYSTRING_H_

struct __mystring_struct {
   char * string;
   int len, maxlen;
};
typedef struct __mystring_struct * Mystring;
#define Mystring_size sizeof(struct __mystring_struct)

Mystring new_mystring (const int len);
void free_mystring (Mystring string);
void append_char_to_mystring ( const char c, Mystring string);
char * cstring_of_mystring(const Mystring string);
Mystring mystring_of_cstring (const char * str);
#endif
```

in `mystring.c`:

```
#include <string.h>
#include "mystring.h"

#define OOM(A) { if (NULL==(A) ){fputs("Out of memory\n",stderr); exit(EXIT_FAILURE);} }
static void check_is_mystring (const Mystring string);
static void double_length_of_mystring ( Mystring string);
```

Later on:

```
static void double_length_of_mystring (Mystring string){
   char * new_mem;
   check_is_mystring(string);

   new_mem = malloc(string->maxlen * 2 * sizeof(char)); OOM(new_mem);
   memcpy (new_mem,string->string,string->len * sizeof(char));
   free(string->string);
   string->string = new_mem;
   string->maxlen *= 2;

   check_is_mystring (string);
}
```

Comment: Are you certain your binary is 64-bit?  What's the output from `file /your/binary/name`?

Comment: Sidenote: Are you aware `sizeof(char)` is 1 by definition?

Comment: You can call `getrlimit()` in your program, specifically with `RLIMIT_AS`, to see whether your process' address-space is limited.

Comment: @Suma - He's lucky he added that - at least that forces the argument to `malloc()` to be computed as a 64-bit `size_t` or `ssize_t` instead of a 32-bit `int` that would overflow, assuming he's actually compiling a 64-bit executable.

Comment: @AndrewHenle Is this any different? I think the int will be sign extended to 64b anyway, in one case  for the malloc expecting size_t, in second case for 64b multiplication.

Comment: @AndrewHenle: will it though? Associativity should be like `(a*b)*sizeof(char)`, so even if `sizeof(char)` has type `size_t`, the relevant multiplication is done at integer type.

Comment: using a variable with name similar to `std::string` is not a good choice

Comment: @EOF - I'm not sure what the C standard says for such a calculation.  I'd opine that code using arguments to a simple `malloc()` call which creates unclear results is **really** bad code.  Provoking references to a coding standard is something good, clean, *understandable* code will never do.

Comment: @AndrewHenle: C11 draft standard, Section `6.5.5 Multiplicative operators [...] multiplicative-expression: multiplicative-expression * cast-expression [...]`. *You* were asserting that the `sizeof(char)` avoided overflow.

Comment: @EOF - I was thinking 6.3.1.8 would be applied first:  "Otherwise, if the operand that has unsigned integer type has rank greater or                   equal to the rank of the type of the other operand, then the operand with signed integer type is converted to the type of the operand with unsigned integer type."

Comment: @AndrewHenle: 6.3.1.8 is applied according to the operator (`*`), which is first applied between `a` and `b` in `a*b*c`. Just tested it, `gcc` agrees with my reading.

Comment: @EOF - Obviously I was incorrect.  I incorrectly recalled 5.1.2.3.  See Example 6, which implies an implementation can in some instances reorder calculations.  I plead "Too early in the morning."

Comment: Never use a pointer to malloc'd memory after that pointer has been passed to free(),   Such activity is undefined behaviour and can/will lead to a seg fault event.   after calling malloc(), always check (!=NULL) the returned value to assure the operation was successful

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It seems you use `int` to keep size of your string. In GCC (and in most other PC platform compilers) this type [is 32b even on 64b platform](http://crasseux.com/books/ctutorial/Integer-variables.html). You should use `size_t` instead.

The mechanism of the failed allocation is as follows:

- 1.2 GB ~= 1288490189
- 2 * 1.2 GB ~= 2576980378, which is over 2^31 (2147483648), after overflow you get -1717986918 in 2nd complement arithmetics
- When calling `malloc`, -1717986918 is sign extended to a 64 b, and then casted to unsigned 64b, which gives you 2^64 - 1717986918, which is only marginally less than 2^64, and definitely more than the memory you have in the system.

Comment: But even signed `int32_t` can hold a value greater than 1.2 GB?

Comment: @EOF: it looks like he doubles the allocation size each time though. So from 1.2 to 2.4GB would be a problem

Comment: On 64-bit *NIX, long is usually 64-bit (LP64), on braindamaged systems it is 32-bits (LLP64).

Comment: @jalf - But the OP's bad accounting of space usage wouldn't cause `malloc()` to return `null`.  Which makes me wonder how the process ends.  Does it exit via the `OOM()` macro posted or does it SEGV?

Comment: @jalf: Even then, while the overflow will be undefined, it is unlikely to produce a zero-value, and even if it does, `malloc()` wouldn't necessarily return `NULL`.

Comment: @AndrewHenle: a negative `int32` sign-extended to a 64-bit value and then converted to a `size_t`? That's going to be a really really big number, which might well cause `maloc` to return `null`.

Comment: @jalf - Good point.  And a great example of why it's worthwhile to make certain all arguments to `malloc()` are of type `size_t`.